# enter button is redirecting to shopping cart

Tags: product-view

please visit this link :

http://kidsdial.com/soft-buddies-lying-love-dog-s-white-10-inch-3621.html

type any zip code and type "enter" using keyboard.

than its rediecting to checkout page.

I want to avoid that redirection ,

file for checking zip code = http://pastebin.com/jpXfM3Be

view.phtml = http://pastebin.com/GuWAYxbz

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace line

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text" maxlength="120" id="zipcode" size="20" name="zipcode">
```

With

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text" maxlength="120" id="zipcode" size="20" name="zipcode" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}">
```

Or

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text" maxlength="120" id="zipcode" size="20" name="zipcode" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}">

<script>
    document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress = function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){
          // Do your ajax process which you are doing on zip-check click button same way.

              new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
                    method: "get",
                    parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                             var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                             $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                             
                             $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                             $('delivery-html').update(json.html); 
                    }
            });

          return false;
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: now it stopped redirecting, after enering zip code and if we press " enter", i want to display the succesfull or failure message.

Comment: edited my answer for showing error or success message same way when you click on check button.

Comment: i pasted your code = http://pastebin.com/FEvyZ4V0, but it's not working. is there anything else i have to do? 

if so please give me the updated code with ajax process

Comment: You need to wrap the ajax request in a separate function. Then execute the function if either the enter key is pressed or the button is clicked.

Comment: @MilanSimek i am new to this ajax, can you please give the updated code

Comment: Let's wait for @Akhilesh Patel to update the code, I don't want to 'steal' his answer.

Comment: Edited my answer. I added your ajax code in my javascript. If that still not work try to remove onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" from that text field.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AkhileshPatel for helping me at this time.....

Comment: Let me know if that work for you.

Comment: @AkhileshPatel It's worked.... i will sleep peacefully now......

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Comment: awesome code @AkhileshPatel Specially  `document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress `